# Fetching data from website - python2 - website is not existing (error 404)

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to get website source in python. My code is like:

```
import urllib2
url = urllib2.urlopen("http://kolekcjoner.nbp.pl")
```

I have problem with this one website - expect this website, everything is working ex. google or anything else. What is funny, I was fetching data from this website 3 days ago, but now this code is not working. Why? What has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are trying to get a page that don't exist...
as you can see the error is:

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

you can use `try` and `except` or use another module that will not raise an exception each time  that there is a HTTP error code (like the `requests` module)

**update:** after checking a bit I found that in the browser the address that you gave works properly so  just for the requests sent by python it gave 404, this means that the server is checking the user agent of the requests and if the user agent isn't allowed/known the server will return an error code (e.g 404). so I checked if that is true by changing the user agent field:

```
>>> requests.get("https://kolekcjoner.nbp.pl/")
<Response [404]>
>>> requests.get("https://kolekcjoner.nbp.pl/",headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103'})
<Response [200]>
```

I hope that this helps you (anyway you should know that the [robot.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) of this site disallow any robot to check this site...)